# Mongoose save with an existing document will not override the same object reference

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I can't figure why this is the behaviour and i will like some explanation.

My goal is to make an update on some document.
because i still want to use mongoose validator then instead of using the update command i first get the document and then i use save on it, so in this way i can still have validations on.

this is my model:

```
var JobSchema = new Schema({
    _id: {type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, required: true},
    _user: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
    data: {type: Object, required: true},
    status: {type: String, required: true}
}, {
    strict: true,
    minimize: false
});
```

when i do this technique of my own to update the document i am updating the data object like this:

```
_.extend(doc.data, newData);
```

but the new data will not be stored.

if instead i do it like this:

```
var lastData = doc.data;
doc.data = data;
_.extend(doc.data, lastData);
```

then it will work.

the only explanation i see is that trying to change an existing object reference will not work, but trying to save a new object does work.

Why is it behaving like this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `data` is defined with a type of `Object`, Mongoose only detects changes to it when you overwrite it by assigning a value to it. When you just make changes to the fields within it, you need to notify Mongoose of the change by calling [`markModified`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-markModified):

```
_.extend(doc.data, newData);
doc.markModified('data');
```

You could also have `extend` create a new object that combines both `doc.data` and `newData`, so that you could assign its result to `doc.data` and trigger the change detection:

```
doc.data = _.extend({}, doc.data, newData);
```

`extend` applies each object in order, so `newData` takes precedence.

Comment: Cool. juat notice that the returned onject is the same so it wont work with the second method you sugjested

Comment: @lobengula3rd Yep, guess you're right. Answer updated to show a way to make that option work.